# What is recommended backup plan for sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Could you briefly say about recommended backup plans depending on database size and backup/restore time.

Currently I have database that is about 1GB in uncompressed state but I expect it will grow very fast so I think it is important to be prepared.

Used system: Windows 2008 Server SQL: SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recovery plans would be dictated by the needs of the business and the resources available - i.e. how critical is the data, what can you afford to lose and how much resilience can you justify for the cost etc.

If you give us more detail about your scenario you'll get some good suggestions coming through but at a basic level you should be looking at a full backup at least weekly (daily if the size doesn't grow too quickly and you can manage it) with more frequent diff backups taken.  Log backups typically should be taken every 15 to 30 minutes depending on throughput.

Oh - and make sure your backups are going to a different drive/array or are getting copied to another off server location so that they're available to recover from if you lose the whole box (an easy mistake I've seen made!)

Finally - test, test, test!  A backup strategy is no good if you don't know how to restore and/or your backups are corrupt.  I'd test weekly.

If you want more resilience then you should look at things like log shipping, mirroring etc...

Answer (score 1):

look at the recommendations/ discussion in t[his serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/51678)